# Where is the variable (such as CONFIG_DM_MMC) of "xxxxxdefconfig file" defined in u-boot ？

Tags: makefile, arm, stm32, u-boot

```
CONFIG_OF_CONTROL=y
CONFIG_OF_EMBED=y
CONFIG_DEFAULT_DEVICE_TREE="stm32h743i-eval"
CONFIG_DM_MMC=y
CONFIG_STM32_SDMMC2=y
```

I can not find oud the variable on the left in u-boot project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -GHrn 'config DM_MMC'
```

yields

```
drivers/mmc/Kconfig:26:config DM_MMC
```

So this is the Kconfig file where you find the definition.

https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kbuild/kconfig-language.html is a good start to learn about configuration variables.

Comment: Better to use, for example, `git grep -n 'config DM_MMC'` (assuming that most likely the sources are derived by `git clone ...`.